# How to set loop in pig latin?

Tags: java, while-loop

I wrote a simple game Pig latin and everything works fine but I want to set a loop when user typed his word or phrase and app showed him an answer, the question should be repeat again

I wrote a loop using while

```
while (true) {
if (input.equals("Exit")){
break;
} else {
// some actions
```

but wherever i would put this piece of code, the answer is looping forever

What I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class piglang {

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String input, output, line;
    public static char firstLetter;
    public static String vowels = "aeiouy";
    public static boolean capital = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 


          System.out.println("enter something: ");

          line = scanner.nextLine(); // scanner checks and returns the input that was skipped
          scanner = new Scanner(line); 

          while (scanner.hasNext()) { // check for other words in line

              input = scanner.next(); // finds and returns next complete token form this scanner          

              firstLetter = input.charAt(0);          

/*first if*/    if ('A' <= firstLetter && firstLetter <= 'Z') { // checking first letter
                    firstLetter = Character.toLowerCase(firstLetter);
                   capital = true;
                } else
                    capital = false;

/*second if*/   if (vowels != null) {  // checking if first letter is a vowelFGriopt;khtyl      mhp
                   output = (input + "ay"); 
                   } 
                else {  
                   if (capital) { // setting first letter to upperCase 
                      output = "" + Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(1));  // char to String conversion
                      output = output + input.substring(2) + firstLetter + "ay";
                   } else {
                      output = input.substring(1) + firstLetter + "ay";
                   }
                }
                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    output.isEmpty();
                }

                System.out.print(output + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you update complete non working code instead of breaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just putting everything currently in your main method inside the block of your `while(true)` loop, one modification you'll have to make is to initialize your Scanner before printing "enter something".  Since you're reusing the same Scanner object to parse the line, it won't be referencing System.in in the next iteration.  You'll also need to check if `line.equals("Exit")` rather than `input.equals("Exit")`, since it's really `line` which represents your entire input.  I'd also recommend using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of just `equals`:

```
while (true) {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter something: ");

    line = scanner.nextLine(); // scanner checks and returns the input that was skipped
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
        break;
    } else {
        scanner = new Scanner(line);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) { // check for other words in line
        input = scanner.next(); // finds and returns next complete token form this scanner          

        firstLetter = input.charAt(0);

        /*first if*/ if ('A' <= firstLetter && firstLetter <= 'Z') { // checking first letter
            firstLetter = Character.toLowerCase(firstLetter);
            capital = true;
        } else {
            capital = false;
        }

        /*second if*/ if (vowels != null) {  // checking if first letter is a vowelFGriopt;khtyl      mhp
            output = (input + "ay");
        } else {
            if (capital) { // setting first letter to upperCase 
                output = "" + Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(1));  // char to String conversion
                output = output + input.substring(2) + firstLetter + "ay";
            } else {
                output = input.substring(1) + firstLetter + "ay";
            }
        }
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            output.isEmpty();
        }

        System.out.print(output + " ");
    }
}
```

}